# give "this" parameter to my callback onclick jquery

Tags: jquery, parameters, callback, onclick

The question is simple:

how can I transform this:

```
$('#foo').on('click', '.bar', function(){
    myCallback(this);
});
```

to that:

```
 $('#foo').on('click', '.bar', myCallback(this));
```

here, this = document, its not what I need. I want the .bar element DOM where click event happening.

So... what can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the myCallback is a function you declared. As described in the demo of jQuery (try.jquery.com) just calling the following:

```
$('#foo').on('click', '.bar', myCallback);
```

will give you the "this" you want inside the function, without parameters.

So the final code should look something like this:

```
$('#foo').on('click', '.bar', myCallback);

function myCallback(){
   alert($(this).html()); //example popup, this is the .bar element
}
```